# How to pass a user relationship in home view laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables:

**Users Table:**

- id
- first_name
- etc..

**Transaction Table:**

- id
- user_id
- etc..

I'm trying to run a check to see if the User id matches the user_id in the Transaction table.

I need to do this from the home view.

What I have:

**User Model:**

```
public function transactions() {
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
}
```

**Transaction Model:**

```
use App\User; ...

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Home Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $currentuserid = Auth::user()->id;
    $transactions = DB::table('transactions')->WHERE($currentuserid , '=','user_id' );

   return view('home');

}
```

**Home view:**

```
@if ($transactions == true)
 //Do stuff
@else
 //Do other stuff
@endif
```

The following keeps returning `true` even if the `Auth id` and `Transaction user_id` are mismatched.

I also thought I could simply do this if statement based on the relationship, but no luck:

```
public function index()
{
   return view('home');
}
-------------
@if (Auth::user()->id == (Auth::user()->transactions->user_id))
```

**UPDATE:** Using the below code errors if there is a mismatch with the `user_id` and 'auth id'. Does not return Mismatch in view. Does return Match if the `id` & `user_id` match.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $currentUserId = Auth::user()->id;
        $transactions = Transaction::where('user_id','=',$currentUserId)->get();
        return view('home', compact('transactions'));

    }
@foreach ($transactions as $transaction)

  @if($transaction->user_id == Auth::user()->id)
  Match
  @elseif ($transaction->user_id != Auth::user()->id)
  Mismatch
  @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: `$transactions = true` will always return true. You probably meant to use `==` or `===`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It seems like you're comparing user id with ids of transactions, which makes no sense since users-transactions are in 1:M relation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your controller the `$transactions` variable receives a query builder instance for the given table, not just a collection.You also forget to send this variable to your view. If you want to get the collection you should use the `get()` method and then loop them like this:

**Controller**

```
$transactions = Transaction::where('user_id','=',$currentUserId)->get();
return view('home', compact('transactions'));
```

**View**

```
@foreach($transactions as $transaction)
{
  if($transaction->user_id == Auth::user()->id)
  // do something
  else
  // do something
}
@endforeach
```

In this case we don't even need to use this `if()` to check if the transactions belongs to the user because we already did that in the controller.

Comment: _"$transactions variable receives a whole collection"_ - no it doesn't. It receives a Builder.

Comment: You're right, i made i mistake,actually the get() method that returns a collection. I edited my answer, thank for leting me notice

Comment: @LucasPiazzi This seems to get me halfway there but errors with `Undefined variable: transaction` if  there is a mismatch in the `auth id` and `user_id`. I updated my question to show this.

Comment: Im not so sure what you want. As i say in my answer, all transactions you send to your view are from the authenticated user, because you filter them in the query. You dont need to use the ```if()``` to verify that. If you want to use the whole transactions table and filter them in the view you could do that using this: ```$transactions = Transaction::all();```